# How to wait until a put finishes before calling another saga?

Tags: redux

I have this code:

```
export function* getOtherData({ payload }) {
  const transactionData = yield call(
    fetchTransactionData);
  yield put(storeTransactionData(transactionData));
  yield call(<anotherSagaDependentOnTransactionData>());
}
```

the `<anotherSagaDependentOnTransactionData>` is dependent on the put action and the reducer completing (transaction being stored in redux state). How do I ensure that the last line does not call until the data is stored in redux state?

Answer (score 0):

The put operation is just an event - there's no way of tying the completion of storing the data with the put.

You need a completion event, which is dispatched when the store operation finishes. your root saga should then take that action and invoke anotherSagaDependentOnTransactionData.

Comment: Where can I emit that completion event/action though? The store operation is na action that gets picked up by a reducer... there isn't really a place to emit another action though?